# XAML binding column number to dynamically created grid children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an ItemsControl inside a grid. It works so that I can generate items when clicking on a button but how do I set the column? The label texts are added inside the ObservableCollection. Now obviously I will end up with a label per text inside my array but I want to give each successive label a higher grid column number. The first having Grid.Column 1, second 2 and so on. How can this be achieved?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyLabelTextList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="?" Style="?" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an object with a string and an integer instead of just a string (as your ObservableCollection), then you could say:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyLabelObjectList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding string_value}" Grid.Column="{Binding integer_value}" Style="?" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You could then maintain the column numbers in the ViewModel somehow.

Comment: Hello Chris, unfortunately the grid column and row is always 0.

Comment: Where is the Grid? If the ItemsControl is inside of a Grid it will have its own Grid.Column property value.

Comment: Hello Chris, indeed its inside my Grid

Comment: Could I put the ItemsControl outside of the grid, bind the rows, columns and content for the labels and then somehow bind all of it inside my grid?

Comment: It turns out that this is not that straightforward. The article in the next comment explains why and also shows how this can be done using an attached property. Alternatively, you could try using a different type of panel if appropriate.

Comment: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html